# some times clustering is giving odd behavior

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet.markercluster

[I am using leaflet clustering in open street map . Most of the time it is working fine . some cases getting some odd behavior like in attached image . but when I click again ,its working fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRiSk.png)

I want all cases it should work fine

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.